# How to get document value except null fields of array and populate afterwards?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a Schema

```
_id:"5ff9b57d2c196236206a0e96"
eventId:"1"
eventName:"Name"
teams:[
 0: {player:"5245552555556"}
 1: {player:"5245552559557"}
 2: null
]
```

Expected result should be like

```
_id:"5ff9b57d2c196236206a0e96"
eventName:"Name"
teams:[
 0: {player: {
      firstName : "player1"
      lastName : "player1"
      email : "player1@email.com"
     }
 1: {player: {
      firstName : "player2"
      lastName : "player2"
      email : "player2@email.com"
     }
    }
]
```

I am running the below query to get the result but if it finds any null value it doesn't return that whole document instead what I need is just to ignore that particular field with null value and populate the rest of the fields

```
const teams = await Event.find({_id:eventId },{"teams":{$ne:null"} }).populate(
        "teams.player",
        "firstName lastName email "
      );
```

Comment: Have you tried to populate directly first? I think population automatically ignores fields with a null value.

Comment: Yes I have tried but it gives the error... Cann't populate the value of null

Comment: Then you might have to go with aggregation. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150132/how-to-exclude-null-values-from-mongoose-populate-query . It is the same problem, but yours might not require that many creteria as  in the post above.